# Recurrence T(n) = T(n-1) + T (n/2) + 1

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am try to find the solution to the recurrence T(n) = T (n-1) + T(n/2) + 1

Whats I have done:

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1 + n/2) + 1
T(n) = 2T(2n/2 - 2/2 + n/2) +1
T(n) = 2 T((3n - 1)/2) +1

if U(X) = T(x/3 + 1) then:

U(X) = 2U(x/2)
U(X) = x

T(n) = 3(N  - 1) + 1
```

This makes any sense ?

Edit: The context is computer science, so when you divide n/2 and n odd you get the next inferior natural number (e.g 1/2 -> 0)

Comment: A couple simple estimates...

If $T(1) \geq 0$ then $T(n) \geq 0$ for all $n$ and thus $T(n) \geq T(n-1)$ for all $n$.  This gives $$T(n) \geq 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) \geq 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} T(1)$$ and $$T(n) \leq 2 T(n-1) \leq 2^{n-1} T(1).$$  Based on [the plot of the values of $T(n)$](http://i.imgur.com/47GuX.png), it looks like $T(n)$ has superlinear growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series is shown in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A033485).  It clearly grows more slowly than the Fibonacci numbers, as you increment by smaller values.  This shows $T(n) \in o(\phi ^n)$.

Comment: This maybe a silly question but \phi will have a value between 1 < \phi <2  ?

Comment: @dreamcrash: $\phi = \frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)$ which is in that interval

Answer (score 3):

Your first line,
$$T(n) = 2T(n-1 + n/2),$$
is already nonsensical. The problems are twofold. First, $T$ is not guaranteed to be additive, so $T(n-1)+T(n/2)$ (the RHS of the original recurrence relation) is not necessarily equal to $T(n-1 + n/2)$. Second, even if $T$ is additive, what you get should be $T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) = T(n-1 + n/2)$, but for some curious reason, you further throw in a multiplicative factor of $2$ to get $T(n) = 2T(n-1 + n/2)$.

At any rate, the sequence generated by the recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$ has been indexed as [A033485](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,2,3,5,7,10,13,18,23,30,37&language=english&go=Search) in OEIS. According to OEIS, when $T(1)=1$, the sequence "**gives the number of partitions of 2n into 'strongly decreasing' parts**". Apparently no closed form solution for $T(n)$ is known.

Comment: thanks for replying I forgot an + 1 in the recurrence

Comment: @dreamcrash: If the recurrence relation without the trailing 1 has no known solution, there is little chance that, with the trailing 1, the relation would have a closed form solution.